# How do i send a response from spring security to an angularjs app when session is timed out?

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

beforehand sorry about my english.
I'm currently developing an application with spring boot and  angularjs as the front end and spring mvc as backend, all this  with spring boot, my problem is, i'm using spring security for simple form login like this

```
http
.csrf().disable()
.authorizeRequests()
.antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
.anyRequest().authenticated();
http
.formLogin()
.loginPage("/login")
.permitAll()
.and()
.logout()
.logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
.invalidateHttpSession(true);
http
.sessionManagement()
.maximumSessions(1)//max session per user
.expiredUrl("/login?expired")
.maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true);
```

I implemented httpsessionlistener as simple as this

```
@Configuration
public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener  {

@Override
public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) {
System.out.println("ok");

}

@Override
public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
  System.out.println("not ok");

}


}
```

and my Application.java as simple as this

```
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    //Get process id, es para el wrapper de java


}
```

and in my application.proterties this
    server.session-timeout=5//Short session just for example

i'm facing 2 situatons, the first, when i logout it says not ok, ok, that means it is creating the session again, and when i try to log in again it says wrong username or password because it only allow 1 session per user.
My logout button is just a simple reques from angularjs like this

```
this.logout=function($scope){

    var LogOut = resource('/sticker/logout');
    LogOut.get(function(message){
        //window.location.href="login?logout";
        console.log(message);
        //scope.message = message.message;
    });

}
```

and the second situation is, when the session expires and i do a request from angularjs it returns the login page, i'm capturing this response with the following code snippet wich i took from [interceptors in angularjs](http://www.webdeveasy.com/interceptors-in-angularjs-and-useful-examples/)

```
app.factory("httpInterceptor", ["$q", "$window", "$log",
                         function ($q, $window, $log) {
                           return {
                            "response": function (response) {
                               var responseHeaders;
                               console.log(response);
                               responseHeaders = response.headers();

                               return response;
                             }
                           };
                        }

                       ])
```

I want to be able to return istead something like an httpresponse og 440 
any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

fwiw 6 months later...

By default it looks like spring security is responding with a 403 once a session times out.  I am getting it to respond with a 401 (Unauthorized) instead by adding the following to the HttpSecurity config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ServerSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        ...
        http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler());
        ...
    }

    private AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler() {
        return (request, response, ex) ->
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, ex.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
```